# How to install Active Directory Users and Computers for Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I want to install the administration tools on a Windows Server 2008 (R1) machine.  On Windows 2003 you installed adminpak.msi, but I can't find such a file for 2008.

Is this a "feature" in Server Manager?  If so what is it named?

---UPDATE---
So I drilled into the server Features list and I have "Remote Server Administration Tools" but it only includes File Services, Print Services and Web Server.

This is a member server in a domain but not a domain controller.  It is Windows 2008 (original) not R2.  Still, why can't it run AD users and computers from this machine?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to open MMC and add the ADUC snap-in?

Comment: I found this question and a few of the answers very helpful.  Why is everyone so stingy with the votes?

Comment: I know this is a very old question but I've just seen it for the first time and after reading the various comments I can only wonder why the OP wants to install these tools if he's not a domain admin. Having the tools but not the permission to use them make this a bit of a pointless exercise.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From Server Manager (available under Administrative Tools), go to "Features", then "Add Features".

**Windows Server 2008 Standard Instructions:**

Expand:

- Remote Server Administration Tools

  - Role Administration Tools

    - Active Directory Domain Services Tools

Then check `Active Directory Domain Controller Tools`.

**Windows Server 2008 R2 Instructions:**

Expand:

- Remote Server Administration Tools

  - Role Administration Tools

    - AD DS and AD LDS Tools

      - AD DS Tools

Then check `AD DS Snap-Ins and Command-Line Tools`.

Feature Includes:

- Active Directory Users and Computers
- Active Directory Domains and Trusts
- Active Directory Sites and Services

Comment: Not available on my Windows 2008 member server.  Maybe restricted by GPO? Or is this a Microsoft thing that those tools are only available on domain controllers or through the addon for Vista/Win7?

Comment: i have it on a workgroup 2008 server.. Can you check again ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that my domain admin's have restricted this by group policy

Comment: I'f they've restricted the gui install the quest AD powershell tools and run  Get-QADObject -Type OrganizationalUnit

Comment: For Server 2008 R2 it is similar but not identical, under Role dministration Tools you need to drill into AD DS and AD LDS Tools -> AD DS Tools -> AD DS Snap-Ins and Command-Line Tools.

Answer (score 6):

The first answer from Mathieu Chateau was basically correct, you do not have to dcpromo to get this.  however, the role option is "AD DS and AD LDS Tools" not "Active Directory Domain Services Tools"

Mike

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right and that it's a feature under Server Manager.  If you dcpromo it, I think they show up automatically based on the roles you give it.  But if it's just a member server, you have to install the feature "Remoter Server Administrator Tools".  When you expand the tree, you can select AD Domain Services Tools, DNS Server Tools, DHCP, etc.  Try looking there, and then make sure that you customize the Start Menu setting so that it shows up.

Edit:   Bah, Joe said it while I was typing this up....

Comment: I would be blind folded and marched in front of the firing squad if I dcpromoed this server.   I am a developer who needs to see how the OUs are laid out for this domain.  I found RSAT under Features, but only have File Services, Print Services and Web Server.  Maybe it can't be done

Comment: Having someone "dcpromo" a server to gain access to a tool set is not good advice.

Comment: I wasn't saying he should dcpromo it, just that "if" he did, he would have access to it.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Mark, so when you go into Server Manager and add Features, you don't have Role Administration Tools->Active Directory Domain Services Tools->Active Directory Domain Controller Tools?  In the KB that Joe linked, it says "Some tools might also work on roles or features that are running on Windows Server 2003".  Are you trying to view/administer a 2003 Domain?  Maybe that's where the hang up is (although I don't see why it would be an issue).

Comment: @Holycryptic, Right I don't have the Active Directory Domain Services Tools available

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9FF6E897-23CE-4A36-B7FC-D52065DE9960&displaylang=en

Comment: See comment for @jscott.  I need to admin tools installed on Windows Server 2008 not Vista.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry. just add the RSAT Feature and then select the RSAT components you'd like on your W2K8 server. This process is the same for W2K8 and W2K8R2. - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730825.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe the MS answer is "Don't manage a domain from a server".

The reason the RSAT tools are only available for download for the client OS is because that's how you're supposed to manage the whole domain.  If you're logging in to a server to do basic domain administrative tasks, you're doing it wrong.  The only reason they exist on the DC is because they must be there for initial domain configuration and for troubleshooting and recovery.  The general idea is that the only real reason to log on to a server is to install or configure software or updates.  Otherwise, if it can be done remotely, do it that way.  Honestly, MS should install a "log on reason" just like they have the "shutdown/reboot reason".

To make a long story short, set up Vista or 7 and administer from there.

Answer (score -2):

Launch the server manager and click on the Features
[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIe8J.png)

[I thought it will be easier to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sPOi.png)